# How to append three columns(all have the same name) within one dataframe using python or Excel VBA Macro?

Tags: python, excel, vba, dataframe, powerquery

I have the following data in Excel now:

[image]

I want to make them to the following format

[image]

I can either do it by a Macro or importing the dataframe into Python.
Please help, either Excel Macro or Python works, or if there's an easier way, please advise.
Thank you.

Comment: Did any answer work for you? If so please toggle the checkmark for that answer to mark question as solved

Answer (score 0):

bring the data into powerquery with data ... from table/range ... [x] headers

within powerquery, paste this code into home... advanced editor...

It bascially stacks columns on top of each other, using the leading and groupsof variables to set the number of leading columns, and number of columns after that to group

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" =  Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, type text})),
leading=0, groupsof=3, // number of leading columns and number of columns after that to group
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each List.Split( List.RemoveFirstN(Record.ToList( _),leading), groupsof) ),
#"Added Custom0" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom0", each Text.Combine(List.FirstN(Record.ToList(_),leading),"|")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom0",{"Custom0", "Custom"}),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn( #"Removed Other Columns", "Custom"),
#"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), "|"), type text}),
#"Merged Columns" = if leading=0 then Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"Custom0"}) else Table.CombineColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"Custom0", "Custom"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.None),"Custom"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Merged Columns", "Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),leading+groupsof))
in #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

close dialog box, then do file...close and load... to get data back into excel as a table